# Scrapy files pipeline for minio storage

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

I've been working on a small scrapy project for the last week and I'm stuck on storing a file in my minio bucket using scrapy pipelines.
I've beeing trying using default and custom pipelines with no results.

My minio policy is already set to public.

**settings.py**

```py
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'tutorial.pipelines.zipsPipeline': 1}
FILES_STORE = 's3://minio/testing'

AWS_USE_SSL = False
AWS_VERIFY = False

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= 'secret'
```

**items.py**

```py
class zipItem(scrapy.Item):
    filecontent = scrapy.Field()
```

**piplines.py**

```py
class zipsPipeline(object):
     def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

**myspider.py**

```py
def step(self, response):
    zipfile = zipItem()
    zipfile['filecontent'] = response.body
    yield zipfile
```

I do not even receive error messages. But the spider ends.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you configure your project to output the extracted data into a local file, does it work, or is the local file empty?

Comment: On local file system works fine

Comment: Do the logs show any error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reference to the minio server like:

AWS_ENDPOINT_URL = 'http://minio.example.com:9000'