# How to Save Scrapy Response Output to minio Pod on a Cluster

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, minio

I saw a similar question in:

[Scrapy files pipeline for minio storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56186284)

But I did not see a successful response.  I am using scrapy to scrape various websites, and I can save the output to a .csv file in my local environment using FEEDS like this:

```
   custom_settings = {
     'FEEDS': {'output.csv' : {'format': 'csv', 'overwrite': True}}
   }
```

But when I move to production, I need to save the response to a minio pod on the cloud.  This is what I am doing presently.  I made outputProcess a global variable based on another response I saw on Stack Overflow about a tangentially related issue.

This is getting me a .csv file saved in my minio pod, BUT unlike when I use FEEDS it's just a continues string.  I can't seem to encode this in a way that: (i) saves each paragraph as a separate entry in the csv; and (ii) captures the cleanup that I am doing in the for loop below where I loop through each paragraph and clean it up.

```
def parse(self, response):
        paragraphs = response.css('p')
        global_variables.outputProcess = paragraphs.extract_first()

        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            yield {
               'Text Paragraph' : paragraph.get().replace('<p>','').replace('</p>','').replace('\xa0','')
            }

def handle(inputs: Dict, minio: Minio, log, **kwargs):
    with minio.get_object(input_bucket, "form.json") as response:
        form = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
        url = form.get("select-url")
        spiderToCrawl = getSpiderToCrawl(url)
        logger.info("This is the url we are crawling: " + url)
        process = CrawlerProcess()
        process.crawl(spiderToCrawl)
        process.start()
        myString = global_variables.outputProcess
        my_csv_object = bytes(myString.encode('utf-8'))
        minio.put_object(input_bucket, "output.csv", io.BytesIO(my_csv_object), len(my_csv_object))
```

I saw in the scrapy documentation references to Google Cloud Storage settings, but nothing about storing in a minio pod in a Kubernetes cluster.

Any assistance would be appreciated, including if there is an easier way to do this - perhaps some modification of the FEEDS settings that scrapy contemplates?

Comment: just write a custom feed exporter that works with your minio bucket

Comment: I would like to do that using 'FEEDS' but I have not seen any precedents as to how exactly to do this.  Does anyone have any suggestions or can point me to a website that has any generic examples re: same?

Comment: The documentation is a good place to start https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#topics-exporters